# What happens when one of the wires/strings supporting the plate is cut?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

[image]

A uniform plate of is suspended using two in-extensible wires. When the wire at end B is cut, then we expect to observe the plate move in an arc with some angular acceleration say $\alpha$ about Centre Of Mass (just after wire is cut).

**My query is:**

Can the uncut wire provide any horizontal force to the plate ? If not, which force causes the motion of the plate in the horizontal direction (as it will rotate in an arc)?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309671/520

Comment: @dmckee Linking a closed question with no answers doesn't really help.

Comment: You'd rather I closed this as homework with no discussion? That was my first inclination, but I try not to wield moderator powers that was except in the most cut and dry cases.

Comment: @dmckee I don't see how this is a homework question. It asks about a specific concept. It doesn't even have any numerical calculation or equations involved.

Comment: @anonymous It definitely did help.  I remembered that question and was trying to remember what people had done and even my thought process when I looked at it.  I couldn't find that question so it's nice he linked it.  It's more a homework question than a conceptual question.  It's about a specific scenario.

Comment: @JMac "remember what people had done"? I don't see any attempt at solving the question on the link.

Comment: @anonymous There's a link to a similar thread in that one which they go through the problem for the other 2 conditions and also give the supposed answer to the original question that this one stems from.

Comment: @JMac Yeah, but there is no attempt at solving "this" particular conceptual question. Anyway, let it be.

Comment: @anonymous It is ok to post your own explanation from the chatroom.

Comment: @sammygerbil Definitely :). Go ahead. You can also have a look at the discussion I had with ja72 on this here (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53144/room-for-anonymous-and-ja72). ja72 gave some really good points to keep in mind :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of mass will not move in an arc because the system has two degrees of freedom. The angle of the wire at *A* as well as the orientation of the block.

It is the angle of the wire at *A* that provides any horizontal force.

[image: FBD]

From the general configuration above you can see how the forces applied to the block are oriented. The kinematics of the problem have **the instant center of rotation of the block somewhere along the dashed gray line** at all times. The reason being that otherwise point *A* will move towards the hanging point.

---

**Edit 1**

Rember, net forces describe the motion of the center of mass and net torques the rotation about the center of mass. So the motion of point *A* is a combination of the linear and angular motion of the block. If you work out the equations you should find $$\ddot{\beta} = \frac{T c^2}{2 I \ell}$$

Comment: Initially angle $\beta$ is $0$ and after that $\beta$ doesn't increase. So it should move in an arc...

Comment: $\beta$ does move away from zero actually. In fact it should go negative first and then positive.

Comment: Let us continue the discussion in chat (http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53144/room-for-anonymous-and-ja72). I have some questions to ask you about your answer.

Comment: The exact diagram I was going to draw...

Comment: On revisiting the answer I couldn't understand the meaning of the sentence: "The reason being that otherwise point A will move towards the hanging point". If the Instantaneous Axis Of Rotation lies on any other point than the dashed line, why should point $A$ move towards the hanging point (in ceiling) ?

Comment: At _any_ instant a 2D rigid body will rotate about a unique point, called the instant center of rotation. At the next instant that point will be different in general. For this problem this point is _always_ along the line of the wire. The reason being that any rotation about a point away from the wire line would cause translational velocity _along_ the wire which is not possible.